# BRAKE ROTOR RUST

Tags: chevrolet, brake-rotor, camaro, appearance

Own a 2011 SS Camaro.  The rust on the centers (hubs) of the rotors has created a significant appearance problem since the factory sport wheels have thin spokes.  Really looks bad.   There's got to be a way to deal with this situation.  I've watched videos where parts (including brake rotors) are dipped or submerged in a rust removing solution.  They seem to come out clean any shinny, but the rust will return immediately on the cast iron rotors if something isn't applied to the cleaned areas.  Interested in recommendations to solve this problem.  Anybody tried a process that works and lasts?

Comment: I always advise against applying anything to rotors as most coatings will affect brake performance. For most cars, plain new rotors are inexpensive and unless you are on a racetrack, most people won't even see the difference between a groved, drlled or plain rotor.

Comment: @tlhIngan how does the finish of the rotor hub affect performance? Brake pads don't go anywhere close to the center of the disc.

Comment: Just because you don't want the product you are applying to get on the braking surface doesn't mean it won't get there. Ever heard of overspray? Running down?

Answer (score 5):

The best way I'm aware of to cure this is to get zinc coated rotors. While the zinc in the wear areas (where the brake is applied) wears off quickly, all the rest of the brake remains coated in zinc and doesn't rust. This leaves it semi-shiney all the time. I had them on my 1994 Z28 which had the C6 Z06 wheels on it and shows quite a bit of the brake disk. They continued to look good the two or so years I owned the car.